# Safari renders inlines as blocks with :before and :after pseudo elements as display:table-row

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm testing on Safari 5.1.7 (on Windows), and surprisingly I don't get the same problem in Chrome. Also works with FF19 and IE9.

I am trying to align two pieces of text above and below a word inside a `<span>`. It works, but as soon as my `<span>` contains other inline elements, they break up on separate lines.

Here's the code:

```
.c { display: inline-table; vertical-align: middle; }
.c:before { content: 'above'; display: table-header-group; }
.c:after { content: 'below'; display: table-footer-group; }
```

Works fine: `<span class="c">word</span>`, renders as
above
word
below

Doesn't work: `<span class="c"><b>word1</b><b>word2</b></span>`, renders as
above
**word1**
**word2**
below

instead of (as in all other browsers):
above
**word1****word2**
below

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3LuHx/11/

I have tried

- `table-row` instead of `table-header-group` / `table-footer-group`,
- to mark the `<b>`'s explicitly as `inline !important`,
- to mark the `<b>`'s as `display:inline-block` + `float:left`,
- to set `.c` to `white-space:nobreak`,

but all with the same result.

It *does* work if I wrap the `<b>`'s in yet another `<span>` and set that to `display:table-row`, but since the `:before` and `:after` in the first place made my DOM scripting so much easier, I would rather not introduce any new elements.

Did anyone have this problem before and come up with a fix?

Comment: This works for me in Safari 6 + Chrome `.c { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up inserting an extra `span` with `display: table-row` -- seems to be the only fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this by adding `float: left` to the elements. Hope that helps!